# How to enable SSL and setup reverse proxy on IIS for a website that was using a custom port

Tags: ssl, iis, web-server, reverse-proxy, web-hosting

we have a legacy website like http://hrsys.com:9199 which is a C++ web application.

We have upgraded the app server to Windows server 2019 and IIS 10. Stilly, we want to issue a business SSL certification for this site and do not change other things, you know it's too old to maintain.

So, here is the plan:
We want to install the certification to IIS and once we access https://hrsys.com then IIS will forward traffic to http://localhost:9199 which means IIS just acts as a reverse proxy.

How can we do this or are there better plans?

Comment: Use IIS ARR to set up reverse proxy rules, https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/extensions/url-rewrite-module/reverse-proxy-with-url-rewrite-v2-and-application-request-routing